# Not sure when to use ':' or '='

Tags: pascal

I am getting this error when compiling my code: "cars2.pp(3,8) Fatal: Syntax error, "=" expected but ":" found"

Here's my code:

```
program vehInfo;

type
    wheels: array [1 .. 6] of integer;
    purchaseYear: array [1919 .. 2051] of integer;
    style = (sports, SUV, minivan, motorcycle, sedan, exotic);
    pwrSrc = (electric, hybrid, gas, diesel);

vehicle = record
    wheel : wheels;
    buyDate : purchaseYear;
    styles : style;
    source : pwrSrc;

end;
var
    myVehicle: vehicle;
    listOfCars: file of vehicle;

begin
    assign(listOfCars, 'hwkcarsfile.txt');
    reset(listOfCars);
    read(listOfCars, myVehicle);
    writeln('wheel type: ' , myVehicle.wheel);
    writeln('year purchased: ' , myVehicle.buyDate);
    writeln('style: ' , myVehicle.styles);
    writeln('power source: ' , myVehicle.source)
    close(listOfCars);
end.
```

I am new to Pascal, any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You need to replace :  to = on six and seven lines, also you make mistakes in lines 26, 27 and 29

Comment: I should put a : after "style" and "pwrSrc"?

Comment: Type declarations requires a `=` sign, just as the compiler is telling you. Variable/field declarations use the `:` sign.

Comment: thank you, that solved my question

Comment: In `type`and `const` blocks, you use `=`. If your constant has a type (typed constant as opposed to true constant), then it has the pattern `name: type = value;`. Types have the pattern `name = type;`. True constants have the pattern: `name = value;`.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite simple: `type` uses `=`, while variable declarations use `:`.

So:

```
type
  wheels = 1..6; // not an array, but a subrange type!
  purchaseYear = 1919..2051; // not an array, but a subrange type!
  style = (sports, SUV, minivan, motorcycle, sedan, exotic);
  pwrSrc = (electric, hybrid, gas, diesel);

vehicle = record
  wheel: wheels;         { a field of a record is a variable }
  buyDate: purchaseYear;
  styles: style;
  source: pwrSrc;
end;

...

var
  myVehicle: vehicle;
  listOfCars: file of vehicle;
```

Subrange types are ordinal types (in this case, both are integers), but within the given range. Any value outside the range is illegal. You don't want to have arrays of numbers, you only want the number of wheels and the year (a number too) the vehicle was purchased. You don't need 133 different dates, do you?